# copying contents of a file to a double array

Tags: c, file, scanf, gets

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me, this is my first time posting a question here so I'm sorry if I didn't include enough information. I have an assignment where we have a file with over 50000 words 1 per line I'm trying to copy it to a double array and later on I'd be able to call the letters for a word for example the word "fish" would be on M[1][] = "fish" --> M[1][2] = i

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
 FILE *file;
 file= fopen("/desktop/textfile.txt", "rwx");
 int words=0;
  while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {//using this to find number of words
    if (ch == '\n'){
        words++;
    }
}
char **M = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*words);
for(int i=0; i < words; i++)
    M[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
```

here lies my problem I'm trying to copy the contents of the textfile onto M[][] but it's not copying anything

```
int a=0;
 while ((fgets(line,50, file)) != EOF){
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(line)-1;i++)
    text[a][i] = line[i];
    a++;}
```

I've tried other things like strcopy and I've tried researching but I didn't understand the errors I was having with those methods, someone please help me.

Comment: `fgetc()` needs a `rewind()` to be back to reading the file from begining again

Comment: Agree with the above `rewind` comment. In addition to fixing that, you could change your `fgets` to copy straight into the `M` array rather than into an intermediate `line` array first. Just need to be sure to remove the `\n` that `fgets` puts at the end of the data. But if you do want to copy it byte by byte as currently being done then you need to fix up the fact that the copy is not terminating the target buffer with a `\0` which is needed for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine on the algorithm side, the syntaxe on the other side.

So here is your main a little reordered

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 int words = 50000; // you need to define words and initialize it correctly

 // We initialize M before processing the file
 char **M = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * words);
 for(int i=0; i < words; i++)
     M[i] = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * 50 );

 FILE *file;
 file= fopen("./desktop/textfile.txt", "r"); // You're only reading so just r
  int a=0;
  while ((fgets(line,50, file)) != NULL && a < words) { // a<words means we don't want to overflow the buffer M
      for(int i=0;i<strlen(line)+1;i++) // strlen returns the length of the string WITHOUT
          M[a][i] = line[i];            // the terminating character (that you want), so +1
                                    // I also replaced text by M since it's the actual array
      }
      a++;   // a++ inside the while not the for, you want to go forth only on a new word.
  }

  /* From here on you can use M the way you want */
}
```

From here this should work, don't hesitate if you still have problems, but pay attention at the order of declaration of you variables. Idealy you would also check if file has been correctly opened, but you can concentrate on that later.

EDIT : You also need to check fgets s for NULL and not EOF, see : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ at Return Value.